# How to setup a while loop with variables

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wanting to setup a while loop in heading 1 that allows a user to input three employees names with hours worked, hourly wage, and total pay. The loop needs to calculate those, account for overtime (over 40 hours receives 1.5x pay for any hours over 40), and display all three employees information after calculating.

What do I need to fix with my code to achieve the desired result?

I've referred to W3Schools and Youtube on "Creating a while loop" and "Declaring variables".

```
<html>
   <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <title>JavaScript Page</title>
   <script language="javascript">


   "<h1> Martha's Diner</h1>"
        // Variables get declared 
       var employeeCount; employeeCount = "3";
       var hoursWorked; hoursWorked = " ";
       var hourlyWage; hourlyWage = " ";
       var notOvertime; notOvertime = "<=40";
       var overTime; Overtime = ">40";
       var totalPay; totalPay = "overTime + notOvertime";
       var employeeName = " ";
       var i = 0;
       /// While Loop
    while (i < employeeCount) {
    employeeName = window.prompt ("Enter an Employee Name");
    hoursWorked = window.prompt ("Enter Hours Worked");
    hourlyWage = window.prompt ("Enter Hourly Wage");

    if (hoursWorked <= 40)
       hourlyWage * hoursWorked;
    i++
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I expected the loop to end and calculate keyed information, but the loop doesn't stop or calculate at all.

Comment: `while (3) {...}` at what point will this condition no longer be fulfilled, so that the loop stops? and where is the `}` in your code? then `Overtime` !== `overtime`. Next `totalPay = "overTime + notOvertime"` Strings are not code, they are just a sequence of characters and don't get executed.

Comment: *The first rule of the Fight Club*: do not use `document.write()` and the like. Once you're experienced enough to understand the problems they cause, you'll also know when they are a viable option. `alert` and `prompt` may be useful for a quick and dirty code, but not for production. Next, `if (hoursWorked <= 40) hourlyWage * hoursWorked;` `12*37` great you've computed a number, what about it? you're not using it anyhow.

Comment: What do you suggest I use instead of document.writeln()? I clearly have no idea what I'm doing. I'm not familiar with javascript at all and this is an assignment for an entry level web app course.

Comment: In this case `"<h1> Martha's Diner</h1>"` just put this into the markup. If you need to create dynamic nodes, there are plenty of methods to manipulate the DOM. you can start here [MDN Node#Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node#Methods)

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. So when you were saying strings are not code, do you mean that the values I have placed in quotes next to the variables aren't going to do anything, and I should remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are running an infinite while loop as any positive integer in java or javascript takes as true and check your closing loop braces.To input three values using while you can try like this:

```
var a=0;
while(a<3)
{
    //your codes
    //your codes
    a=a+1;
}
```

this will execute 3 times

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the loop. What would I need to use to keep track of the information that is keyed into window.prompt for the three loops?

Comment: change your variables to arrays

Comment: yes you can either get them in separate variables or can use a variable array for easy access